# X509Certificate2.Verify() runs into error but certificate is working

Tags: c#, .net, validation, x509certificate2, ca

My experience is to have an optional explicit certificate validation to get more detailed information if certificate validation fails. Typically the errors are very superficial without explicit validation.

Up to now this was working fine and helped in some situations but now this code returns a validation error. But when explicit validation is disabled the certificate is working fine.

> Error in certificate-chain [RevocationStatusUnknown] [The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.].

> Error in certificate-chain [OfflineRevocation] [The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.].

This is the code the handles explicit validation if enabled:

```
var runValidation = true;
X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

var store = new X509Store("storename", "storelocation");
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certs = store.s.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "dn", false);
var e = certs.GetEnumerator();
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    certificate = e.Current;
    break;
}

if (!runValidation) { return certificate; }

var valid = certificate.Verify();
if (!valid)
{
    var chain = new X509Chain();
    if (!chain.Build(certificate))
        foreach (var status in chain.ChainStatus)
            loggingService.Error($"Error in certificate-chain [{status.Status}] [{status.StatusInformation}].");
        
    return null;
}

return certificate;
```

The certificate is used for authenticating client:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("url");
// ... further settings ...

var cert = FunctionToGetCertWithCodeAbove();
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

I don't understand why explicit validation fails but anyhow the certificate is working.

Comment: Are you operating behind a firewall by chance?

Comment: Most likely, the certificate is either ignored on server or server ignores client certificate validation errors. If later, then your application is seriously flawed.

Comment: I agree totally that my app would be seriously flawed if validation errors are ignored. I did not change any validation rules. Regarding firewall: I'm sure there are firewalls since it is a big company network.

Comment: Does the HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() perform any validation of the clientcertificate?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an infrastructure problem. Application is working fine.